# Search by a special cell in the wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

On my page of WP and more specifically in the database added columns in the table 'post'.

I called it "special" and now I would like to search displayed the first posts that will have a "special" = 1.

Is there any plugin?

Is it enough to change something in the settings?

If not, how do I set the search engine to first showing posts that "special" = 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't add any column to post table. It is not the wordpress way. Instead use post meta

```
add_post_meta($post_id, 'special', 1);
```

Then use WP_Query

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'your_post_type',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'special',
            'value'   => 1,
        ),
    ),
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

This will fetch you the posts you are looking for.